# Flask-SQLAlchemy unittests failing InvalidRequestError: Table '{table_name}' is already defined for this MetaData instance

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building an API service with Flask, SQLAlchemy and more recently integrating the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension. While I can run the app standalone and make API calls successfully, I am hitting a problem attempting to run unittests. I believe the issue is with importing the db.Model types more than once.

The exception is this:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/james/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 322, in run
    self.setUp()
  File "/Users/james/Documents/workspace/trustmile-backend/trustmile/tests/test_users.py", line 28, in setUp
    from trustmile.app.users.model import User, ConsumerUser, CourierUser, AuthSession, Location, UserAddress, db
  File "/Users/james/Documents/workspace/trustmile-backend/trustmile/app/users/model.py", line 23, in <module>
    class User(db.Model, UniqueMixin, TableColumnsBase, References):
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 536, in __init__
    DeclarativeMeta.__init__(self, name, bases, d)
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 55, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 88, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 103, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._setup_table()
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 394, in _setup_table
    **table_kw)
  File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api-p2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 398, in __new__
    "existing Table object." % key)
InvalidRequestError: Table 'tmuser' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

My **init**.py in /app/ (the top level) is like this:

```
__author__ = 'james'

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import config
from app.messaging import EmailHandler

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='api/static', static_url_path='/static')
app.config.from_object(config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

EmailHandler.setup(config.EMAIL_API_KEY_DEV)
from app.api.consumer_v1 import bp as blueprint
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix = '/consumer/v1')
app.test_request_context()
```

Running that with:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

Works great.

The beginning of my test_users.py looks like this:

```
__author__ = 'james'
from trustmile.app.exc import InvalidEmailException
from trustmile.app.exc import InsecurePasswordException
from nose.tools import assert_true, raises
from trustmile.app.users.model import User, ConsumerUser, CourierUser, AuthSession, Location, UserAddress, db
from . import TransactionalTest



email_address = 'james@cloudadvantage.com.au'
test_password = 'mypassword'


class UserTest(TransactionalTest):



    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(UserTest, cls).setUpClass()

    def setUp(self):
        super(UserTest, self).setUp()

    def test_create_user(self):
        user = User()
        db.session.add(user)
```

It must be fairly common way to do unit testing and yes I'm sharing the SQLAlchemy object between modules (which I'm sure is bad practice). I'm running it with nosetests and the error occurs as the code is initialised. Sorry for the lengthy question, hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue. I'm guessing this is a Flask-SQLAlchemy issue

Comment: This is probably a case of importing the `models.py` twice with distinct names...

Comment: @silverdagger, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

right below `__tablename__`